# How to add a timeout in React Native App before a user can use the app again after closing it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make an Attendance taking App with React Native.
I want the user to be able to mark their attendance only once for every hour.
So if a user tries to open the app again, he is locked out for certain time period.

I am out of ideas how I can implement it.

Comment: use asyncstorage to record last use of the app, when the app launches again check it against the recorded data in the storage, if it's less than 1 hour, lock it